# Root for or support (American English usage)

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I had another question related to AmE usage....

I found out in a Dictionary that "support" isn't common in AmE and it is BrE. So is that so? Google Ngram says that "root for" isn't really common..

> Which team are you supporting?
>
> Which team are you rooting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

In AmE, I hear "rooting for" far more often than "support" in this sense, and I pretty much never hear "supporters" used to mean "fans of". But "Which team are you a fan of" is more common yet.  From my reading, "support" and "supporters" are indeed common in BrE.

Oddly, "support" is used quite often in AmE is similar but non-sports contexts:

> - I support the Bach Consort (usually meaning that I donate money)
> - I support the Purple party (meaning that I vote for them, or advocate for their policies)
> - I support gender equality. (meaning that I am in favor of it)

I don't know why US-English doesn't commonly use "support" ,in a sports context, but it doesn't seem to do so very often.

Comment: Is "fan of" more common than "root for"?

Comment: And one question (if you know) : why has this question turned yellow? (On the thread list)

Comment: @It's both are common. I think "fan of" may be more common, but i'm not at all sure, and this is the kind of thing where I don't trust google Ngrams to be representative. Oh, and I don't see the questiion listed as yellow, and have no idea why you do or anyone would.

Comment: And what about: "Which team are you cheering for?"

Comment: @It's Yes "cheering for" and "cheering on" can bo0th be used, with about the same meaning. I would be more apt to use these in the context of a specific game or event, not to indicate a continued support of a team.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish It seems to me that, in general, "*Which team do you* ***follow***?" would be more idiomatic. Or even *"What's your **favourite** team?"*